# BreezeJs Local query returns with entity and empty entity

Tags: angularjs, breeze

I'm closely following John Papa's pluralsight course on Angular and Breeze. I also use Entity Framework 6.

At load time, I call a Prime function that clears the cache:

```
function clearCache() {
    var cachedParents = manager.getEntities('Parent'); // all invoices in cache
    cachedParents.forEach(function (parent) { manager.detachEntity(parent); });
    zStorage.clear();
    manager.clear();
}
```

and then, loads the info:

```
return EntityQuery.from('Parents')
    .where('applicationUser.email', '==', userId)
    .expand('Address, Children')
    .toType(entityParent)
    .using(self.manager)
    .execute()
    .then(querySucceeded, self._queryFailed);
```

that calls the controller with

```
[HttpGet]
public IQueryable<Parent> Parents()
{
     return _repository.Parents;
}
```

That returns one record...

Later, on the loading of the view, in the same repository, I request the parent entity from the local cache as follows:

```
var cachedParents = EntityQuery.from('Parent')
    .toType(entityParent)
    .using(self.manager)
    .executeLocally();
```

**THIS ONE BRINGS TWO ENTITIES**, the correct one with Id, name, addres, etc. but also brings an empty entity with Id 0.

I've checked and even if I call the local query right after the remote query, it still brings the correct record AND the empty record.

I also reviewed the response and the json object comes correctly formatted and with only one record.

I've tried clearing the zstorage, the entity manager, detachment of the object, but nothing seems to explain or clear the empty entity.

This behavior only happens in the Parent entity type. No other type shows anything wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

One way to debug this is to subscribe to the [entityManager.hasChangesChanged](http://www.breezejs.com/sites/default/files/apidocs/classes/EntityManager.html#event_hasChangesChanged) event.

This event will be fired when the "ghost" entity is added. This way, you can trace the call stack by putting a breakpoint inside the event.

So first, ensure that after the `clearCache` call, the entityManager is empty. (Side note: the call to individually detach the parent entity via `manager.detachEntity` is actually redundant since you're already calling the `manager.clear` method at the end)

Then, put a breakpoint inside the `hasChangesChanged` event as you debug.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

My bet is that you have code that adds a "nullo" (a placeholder entity with id=0) to the EntityManager. There is such code in John's sample and you might be calling it unintentionally.

To demonstrate that Breeze is NOT adding such a nullo itself,

- set a breakpoint before the query
- set a breakpoint at the top of the `querySucceeded`
- confirm that there are no entities in cache at all before you query for "Parents" (e.g., `manager.getEntities()` returns nothing).
- confirm at the top of `querySucceeded` that the query results in exactly ONE entity in cache (e.g., `manager.getEntities()` returns the lone "Parent" entity).

**FWIW**, there is no need to detach individual entities of type "Parent" if you are going to call `manager.clear()`. That call detaches every entity in the manager's cache, including the "Parent" types.